# Tensorflow dataset drops dimension when calling model.fit

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to convert my data to use the tf.data.Dataset API, it was done as follows:

```
# x_train.shape: (7072, 357, 66, 1)
# x_val.shape:   (1248, 357, 66, 1)
# y_train.shape: (7072, 2)
# y_val.shape:   (1248, 2)

ds_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train)).batch(batch_size)
ds_val = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_val, y_val)).batch(batch_size)
```

Which correctly gives me a batch shape of:
`<BatchDataset shapes: ((None, 357, 66, 1), (None, 2)), types: (tf.float64, tf.float64)>`

However, when trying to train my model I get a dimensionality error, where it seems as if the first dimension of the tensor slice (the 357 one) has been dropped:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_1 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 66, 1)
```

All I did was pass the above datasets as normal:

```
history = model.fit(
          ds_train,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=ds_val,
          callbacks = my_callbacks)
```

Edit:
On this model and instantiation

```
def create_model():
    initz = keras.initializers.GlorotUniform(seed=seed)
    model = Sequential() 
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=5, kernel_size=(16,66), padding='same', input_shape=(w,66,1))) 
    model.add(layers.Activation(activations.relu))
    model.add(Reshape((w, 66*5)))
    model.add(LSTM(16))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax')) 

    model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy']
              )
    model.summary()
    return model

tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver()  
tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(tpu)
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(tpu)
tpu_strategy = tf.distribute.TPUStrategy(tpu)

with tpu_strategy.scope():
    model = create_model()
```

Comment: add your model definition.

Answer (score 1):

The input layer for your model looks like this:

```
Conv2D(filters=5, kernel_size=(16,66), padding='same', input_shape=(w,66,1))
```

where you specify the `input_shape` as `(w, 66, 1)`. The error suggests a mismatch between the input layer and the input tensor from `tf.data`/

I suggest removing `input_shape` in the first Conv2D and try inserting an `Input` layer beforehand like this:

```
model = Sequential() 
model.add(Input(shape=(357, 66, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=5, kernel_size=(16,66), padding='same'))
```